# How to calculate Mean Average Precision at a fixed IoU threshold?

Tags: precision-recall, object-detection, image-segmentation, average-precision

Papers such as COCO and the VisDrone often list MAP, MAP50, MAP75 in their evaluation criteria. To my understanding, MAP is the averaged AP for all classes across an IoU range (0.5 - 0.95 for example), and AP is the area under the precision-recall curve, a curve plotted using precision and recall values at each IoU step.

My question is, by setting a fixed IoU, wouldn't that result in a single precision value and a single recall value? and if so, how is precision-recall curve built in order to calculate AP?